# What is Cache Prefix in Blur.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is Cache Prefix in [Blur.js](http://blurjs.com/)? I am trying the demo code for `Blur.js` and getting an error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://localhost:44300/none
```

I understand it has something to do with `cacheKeyPrefix: 'blurjs-',    //Prefix to the keyname in the localStorage object`. Even if I exclude this I still get the same error. What Object am I suppose to point this to? The documentation in the link is limited. Please if you have used `Blur.js` help me out.

```
$('.target').blurjs({
    source: 'body',         //Background to blur
    radius: 5,          //Blur Radius
    overlay: '',            //Overlay Color, follow CSS3's rgba() syntax
    offset: {           //Pixel offset of background-position
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    optClass: '',           //Class to add to all affected elements
    cache: false,           //If set to true, blurred image will be cached and used in the future. If image is in cache already, it will be used.
    cacheKeyPrefix: 'blurjs-',  //Prefix to the keyname in the localStorage object
    draggable: false        //Only used if jQuery UI is present. Will change background-position to fixed
});
```

Comment: Why do you think it has to do with that variable?

Comment: It's more likely because that you've included wrong path for your file and it's cannot be loaded

Comment: @PaoloCasciello I am using a minimized script of Blur.js. Just about to locate the exact line with the full script. but in the minimize script the error is pointed to a line of code that has sth to do with `CacheKeyPrefix`

Comment: Ok got it figured out. You need to point `source:'body'`. Because my image is on the `html`, `body` image was returned null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem. The `source` variable must select any element which has image that you want to be blurred.

So if I have a div like

```
<div class="blurry">
<div class="blurrys-kids"><div>
</div>
<style>
.blurry {
background: url('../Images/BlurryHasBadKids.jpg');// Important for blurry to have a Background Image
}
</style>
```

Then you have to use Blur.js as

```
$('.blurrys-kids').blurjs({
    source: '.blurry',
    overlay: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.33)',
    radius: 10
});
```